# Can I use String Join func with other function

Tags: javascript, string, typescript, join

```
let sendData = '';
sendData = `${sendData}email=${currentUser.email}`;
sendData = `${sendData}&first_name=${first_name}`;
sendData = `${sendData}&last_name=${last_name}`;
sendData = `${sendData}&nationality=${nationality}`;
sendData = `${sendData}&date_of_birth=${date_of_birth}`;
sendData = `${sendData}&gender=${gender}`;
sendData = `${sendData}&id_type=${id_type}`;
sendData = `${sendData}&photoid_res=${photoid_res}`;
sendData = `${sendData}&selfie_res=${selfie_res}`;
sendData = `${sendData}&kyc_level=L1`;
```

I am trying to shorten this code by using Join func! Can you give me some idea to shorten this with that function?

Answer (score 0):

Just put everything in an array and then join them:

```
let sendDataArray = [
    `email=${currentUser.email}`,
    `first_name=${first_name}`,
    `last_name=${last_name}`,
    `nationality=${nationality}`,
    `date_of_birth=${date_of_birth}`,
    `gender=${gender}`,
    `id_type=${id_type}`,
    `photoid_res=${photoid_res}`,
    `selfie_res=${selfie_res}`,
    `kyc_level=L1`
];

let sendData = sendDataArray.join('&');
```

I used a separate variable in the example above for clarity. But once you understand the code you can just do it in a single expression:

```
let sendData = [
    `email=${currentUser.email}`,
    `first_name=${first_name}`,
    `last_name=${last_name}`,
    `nationality=${nationality}`,
    `date_of_birth=${date_of_birth}`,
    `gender=${gender}`,
    `id_type=${id_type}`,
    `photoid_res=${photoid_res}`,
    `selfie_res=${selfie_res}`,
    `kyc_level=L1`
].join('&');
```